# Win32API: Ejecutar una ventana de diálogo con controles (Sliders y RadioButtons) y enviar los valores a una función

Tags: c++, diálogo, winapi

Tengo un programa que captura video de una webcam, pero necesito ejecutar - antes de grabar - una ventana de diálogo con determinados controles (Dos sliders/trackbars y un par de radiobuttons) los cuales envíen valores al ser elegido el botón de Aceptar (En el caso del botón Cancelar, se envían valores"por defecto").

Quiero ejecutar dicha ventana con controles antes de que se cree el objeto grabador (Para que los valores emitidos por los controles se transmitan a dicho objeto).

¿Cómo puedo crear la ventana de diálogo con controles?
¿Cómo puedo enviar los valores?
¿Cómo la ejecuto antes de que empiece a grabar?

Comment: Quizás te ayuden estas preguntas que se han hecho en stackoverflow en inglés: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111809/can-i-return-a-custom-value-from-a-dialog-boxs-domodal-function) y esta (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196004/c-getting-data-from-a-dialogbox). Se parecen mucho a lo que preguntas tu. Sin más información de lo que ya has hecho poco más podemos hacer.

Comment: Continúo aquí ya que no me entra todo en un comentario.
Por cierto, para crear la ventana la puedes diseñar con el propio editor de ventanas que tenga el entorno de desarrollo que estés usando (hacerlo a mano es un infierno). Para mostrarla, con las funciones que te de la API de windows o el C++ que utilizas, antes de llamar al código que graba de la webcam.

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta un ejemplo del código que tienes, hasta donde has llegado, que has intentado y cuales son tus dudas concretas. Lee [mcve]